# How to create aspx page on runtime and place literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an requirement where i have to display some content on iframe dynamically. Let me explain my scenario. I have a form where i have to display some html text. Earlier what i did is , i placed a literal on the form and fill it with HTML text. All worked fine but , the text alignments of the displayed html gets overriden by the page css.
So what i want now is that, instead of literal, i place an iframe. Now at page load event , i will generate a aspx dynamically and place a literal control and fill that literal control with the html text. And then will display that aspx page in the iframe.

So i would like to know the following things:

- Is this a good idea to hold heavy
  text , more than 20K of chars in
  memory, dynamically generate aspx
  page at runtime.
- If any workaround to not to inherit
  the page css inside the    literal
  displayed.
- Any other approach better than my approach.
- Way to implement my approach(iframe and dynamic aspx).

--- **I am using ASP.NET / C# 4.0**

Loads of questions...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmRan, if this actually is a css problem, I would first try to create separate css styles for that content and use with the first solution you did. For example, wrap your dynamic content widh

```
<div id="dynamicContent">
```

tag and place

```
#dynamic {}
```

style settings inside your css file.

I don't think the Literal control has a CssClass property so you would have to use Label instead, or some other technique.

I would try to stay away from IFrame solutions if possible.

Hope this helps.